# PHP 7.0.22 : mod_deflate enabled & .htaccess in place but doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: apache, .htaccess, deflate

I have a website setup using Plesk within PHP 7.0.22 being run as FPM application served by Apache.

So far everything has been running great however when I attempted to enable compression within .htaccess as I normally would nothing appears to be compressed.

```
#SERVER COMPRESSION
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype

# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/svg "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
 ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

# 1 day for most static assets
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

I contacted the server admin to enquire incase the mod_deflate module wasn't enabled but have been assured that it is, having been given screen shoots as proof.

Kind of stumped at this point any ideas where I should go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because the hosting environment was setup using a mish mash of both Apache & Nginx.

The server admin updated the Nginx directives to enable compression.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly question and I'm not sure which version of Plesk you are using, but:

- Do you have a "Apache & nginx Settings" icon in Plesk?
- If so, is "Serve static files directly by nginx" disabled? If not, try disabling it and see if it makes a difference.*
- You can also try playing with the other proxy checkbox options.

*(*If mod_pagespeed is enabled, it would be better to leave it enabled but only have "htm html" in it, else they will appear blank.)*